# Quantum Field Theory and the Standard Model by Matthew Schwartz - Solution's manual

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, standard-model, specific-reference

Is there a way I can find a solution's manual for Matthew Schwartz's "Quantum Field Theory and the Standard Model" book?

Comment: What do you mean by "find"? Like where to purchase it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because solution manuals do not fall within the scope indicated by the site's consensus on resource recommendations and specific references.